# Firebase function transaction handle null value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use firebase function transaction, but as I see there is no official way to handle the first *cached* null value...

I'm trying to do the following:

```
var team = event.data.child('team').val();
  var tip = event.data.child('tip').val();
  console.log('tip: ' + tip + ' | team: ' +team)

  const pathToValue = admin.database().ref('users/' + event.params.userId + '/coins');
  const pathToTeamBetsValue = admin.database().ref('matches/' + event.params.matchId + '/opponents/' + team + "/bets");
  return pathToValue.transaction(function (coins) {
    if (coins) {
      if (coins >= tip) {
        pathToTeamBetsValue.transaction(function (teamBets) {
          if (teamBets) {
            teamBets = teamBets + tips;
            return teamBets;
          }

        });
        admin.database().ref('bets/' + event.params.matchId + '/' + event.params.userId + '/status').set('inProgress');
        coins = coins - tip;
      }
      else {
        console.warn(event.params.userId + " new bet on match " + event.params.matchId + " was not successfull! (not enough coin)")
        //return coins;
      }
    }
    return coins;
  })
```

so far as you can see I get some value which what should be decreased from the user's coins... unfortunately till now I could only get the behaviour which sets null in the user's coin value.. please help

Comment: with ... .then(...) in the end of the call seems to fix it, but I'm still looking for the official way